# How to Send sms from ipod?

Tags: iphone

Hi i want to send sms from ipod and also i will check whether it is being recieved by receiver (user) or not ?

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "iPod", you mean "iPod Touch", this is a very easy thing to do.  You can use AOL Instant Messenger to send an SMS to a phone number in the form +18885551212.  Or you can do the same from iChat.

Also, see the application "Fring" for a great messaging / voip / SMS aggregator.

Comment: You can't actually ever tell if an SMS is received by the other user unless they send you a message back.

Comment: Actually you can... you can ask for a receipt... and you'll be notified then the user reads the message.

Answer (score 0):

No*, and no.

*You can use Wi-Fi to connect to an external SMS gateway, but you'll almost certainly have to pay for it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use an app called "TextFree" on an ipod touch to send or receive text messages.